# Why is the text box not appearing?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck in something I believe it's really simple but I haven't found a way to understand the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<main>
<div class="form">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Medidas do Aquário:</legend>

          <label for="comprimento">Comprimento:</label>
          <input type="text" name="comprimento" id="comprimento">

          <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
          <input type="text" name="altura" id="altura">

          <label for="largura">Largura:</label>
          <input type="text" name="largura" id="largura">

          <label for="preco">Preço:</label>
          <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
<script>
          function multiplyBy()
          {
                  num1 = document.getElementById("comprimento").value;
                  num2 = document.getElementById("altura").value;
                  num2 = document.getElementById("largura").value;
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2 * num3 ;
          }

<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id ="result"></span>
</p>
      </fieldset>
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The paragraph 'The Result is:' is not showing:

[image]

Comment: you forgot the closing `</script>` tag, ooh you didn't forget, but you placed it at the wrong place

Comment: The `</script>` tag is there, but it is in the wrong place.

Comment: Hello, the closing ```</script>``` tag is there (4th line counting from below).

Comment: move it up before the `<p>The Result is :....`

Comment: With this change, I was able to see it now, thank you very much!
But... when I make the calculation, it doesn't show the result... I will work on this for the next days and come back if stuck :)
Stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

Moving the `</script>` tag as shown below should fix the problem.

```
<script>
      function multiplyBy()
      {
           num1 = document.getElementById("comprimento").value;
           num2 = document.getElementById("altura").value;
           num2 = document.getElementById("largura").value;
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2 * num3 ;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: With this change, I was able to see it now, thank you very much! But... when I make the calculation, it doesn't show the result... I will work on this for the next days and come back if stuck :) Stay safe!

Comment: The issue might be because you haven't declared any of the JavaScript variables. To do this put `var` before the variable name.